# Javascript Dialog box w/ Multiple Buttons

Tags: javascript

Is there a type of Javascript dialog box (similar to alert) that offers customizable, multiple buttons (besides "OK") and will return some sort of indication of which button was clicked? I am *not* looking for a JQuery or third-party dialog/modal box, I'm just wondering if there's something already built into Javascript. As far as I've researched, Javascript only offers alert(), confirm(), and prompt().

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry nothing like that available to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want something more than the built in alert, confirm and prompt which you already know about, then you will need to use a third party script/library or develop your own modal windows.